# If Date is Less Than Current Date by 15mins then do something

Tags: javascript, function, date, datetime

I have been trying to work on something with dates and I was wondering how to check if it is less than 30mins or 15mins difference then should call a function.

```
let btnCheck = document.querySelector('button');
let result = document.querySeletor('h1');

let current = new Date();
let date = new Date('01/01/2021');

btnCheck.addEventListener('click', () => {
let ms1 = current.getTime();
let ms2 = date.getTime();

result.innerText = ms2 < ms1;
});
```

So far it results in a true or false but I wanted to add something if the current date is less than the date by 15mis or 30 mins show a button.

Update: Using Moment Library it can be possible through something like this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/
But I'm only going to use this for a one-time function.

Thank you in advance! Much appreciated!

Comment: Just install moment library.

Comment: I'm more about learning how to do it in pure js. I have checked that moment has 'durations'. It would probably be easy if a subtract the date from the current date and then compare it. I still don't know how to do that. In theory, It sounds easy in my head. Thanks though!

Comment: For everyone who suggests installing moment (not only Vasyl), – please, read [this article from the moment's docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). Also, installing a gigantic library to use just one little function that can be easily implemented is a bit much.

Comment: There are many questions and answers about getting the [difference between to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+dates) already.

Answer (score 0):

As [Vasyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5952279/vasyl-moskalov) already said you can use the moment library for this.

If you really want to use pure javascript the documentation of the Date object in JS is pretty good. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#calculating_elapsed_time). You have to take into account that the difference is given in milliseconds, thus the calculations. Based on the documentation example i would do it like so (You are free to refactor!):

```
let btnCheck = document.querySelector('button');
let result = document.querySelector('h1');

let current = new Date();
let date = new Date('01/01/2021');

btnCheck.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let ms1 = current.getTime();
  let ms2 = date.getTime();

  //This checks if the difference is less than 15 minutes
  if((ms1 - ms2) / 1000 / 60 < 15 ){
  };

  //This checks if the difference is less than 30 minutes
  if((ms1 - ms2) / 1000 / 60 < 30 ){
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
const btnCheck = document.querySelector('button');
const result = document.querySeletor('h1');

let current = new Date('2011/10/09 12:00');
let date = new Date('2011/10/09 11:30');

btnCheck.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const diff = Math.abs(current - date);
    if (diff === 15 || diff === 30) { // if (diff <= 30) { 
        result.innerText = diff;
        btnCheck.disabled = false;
    }else{
        btnCheck.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Creating Dates from unsupported string formats is not a good idea, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) This tests whether the difference between the dates is exactly 15 ms or 30 ms, it doesn't test for minutes.